# Width-change of <div> inside <td> changes <td>-width

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, html-table

I do have a table where I want to show the complete cell-content on hover.

I got this working with css, but now I'm facing a bug with all browsers except Chrome.

HTML extract:

```
<table><tr>
  <td class="hover-text" style="width: 99px">
    <div style="width: 99px">A long text</div>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

CSS extract:

```
.hover-text div{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.hover-text:hover div{
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This works all fine, except if I use **any browser but Chrome**, there is just **one row** and there is a **horizontal scroll-bar**. Then the cells are strangely resized. Without one of this conditions, I got no problems. Unfortunately the HTML is given from the framework I use.

I tried all sort of things, but at this point I'm at a loss..

You can see this issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FmY5R/4/) if you resize the table so that there is no horizontal scroll-bar, everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm sure you just typo'd here but you have `<td class="hover-text"` and then CSS you call `.text-hover`

Comment: I'm sorry, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FmY5R/10/

```
td{
   display: inline-block
}
```

But I'm still not sure what caused the bug..

Answer (score 0):

Your `td` element has a class of "hover-text" whereas your CSS uses the selector `.text-hover`. This means that the CSS you've provided has no affect on the HTML you've provided.

To fix this, either change your `td` element's class to "text-hover" or change your CSS selectors to `.hover-text`.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind the names you keep in html markup and you use in css. Even a professional may confuse this way.

```
.hover-text div{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.hover-text:hover div{
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    width: auto !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: of course this works (sorry for the typo)
but under my described conditions there's a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your CSS, Now its working fine for me.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FmY5R/)**

**CSS**

```
.hover-text div{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
.hover-text:hover div{
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1;
  width: auto !important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I updated this, problem still occours: http://jsfiddle.net/FmY5R/1/
(the jumping issue I fixed already)

Comment: I don't want the actual table to jump, it should more look like a tooltip, but its definitely better than before.

Comment: Can you describe your desired output?

Comment: like it looks in e.g. chrome (I left out the background-color styling and the text-jump).
Just show the whole text in front of the right cell.

Comment: Mozilla and chrome are rendering samething here. Do you have a screenshot? Which version are you using?

Comment: sure: http://postimg.org/image/ok1i8ermr/
the ff version doesn't matter, tried from 15 to 26
chrome is the most current. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeah this looks the same in both browsers. But unfortunately its not what I want..